# Html Divs going underneath another DIv Automatically

Tags: css, html

I have a couple divs and they are set up to be sepereate. but when I load the page they all go underneath the first div that is created. So the example below SiteFullControl is the first div, everything just falls underneath here when the page load. any ideas?

```
 <div id="SiteFullControl" >
    <fullcontrol:FullAlbum runat="server" ID="FullControlAlbum" />
</div>
 <div id="SitePartialControl" >
    <partialalbum:partialalbum ID="partialcontrolalbums" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="SiteViewOnlyAlbums" class="">
    <viewonly:viewonly ID="viewonlyalbums" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="SitePublicAlbums" class="">
    <publicalbum:publicalbum ID="publicalbum" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="SiteFavoriteAlbums" class="">
    <favoritealbum:favoritealbum ID="favoritealbum" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="SiteFriends" class="">
    <friends:friends ID="friend" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="SiteCreateAlbum" class="">
    <createalbum:createalbum ID="createalbums" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Example of whats happen when the page load

```
<div id="SiteFullControl" >
<fullcontrol:FullAlbum runat="server" ID="FullControlAlbum" />
```

I checked the css with firebug and it does not have any position for the css.

Comment: My guess is they are all positioned absolute, but without seeing CSS we can't really be sure.

Comment: check with any html/css inspector (firebug, chrome dev tools) where they get the position:absolute from

Comment: By "underneath" do you mean "behind"? Like stacked on top of each other or one above the other?

Comment: I edited my post. Seems like it cut off some of my example post. but the css does not have a position for the Div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this CSS rule, it may work:
    display:block;

no more help can be given without accessing CSS properties.